# How to pixel-perfect mockup this border?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to mockup this design:

[image: desired design]

But, I can't render the red border correctly. I tried with the obvious solution:

```
border: 1px solid #939393;
border-left: 4px solid red;
```

But It's affected by the top and bottom borders, leaving the red stripe with diagonal corners, as you can see in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/anp0e03k/

Is there any way correct way to fix this?

The only thing that I can think is to add a div inside with red background and negative margins on top and bottom, but it seems to be an overkill and would love to find something that doesn't ruins the html semantic.

Comment: Use a different browser, some render this way, some render that...

Comment: Is there any cross-browser way to do this?

Comment: Maybe create a border using `before`

Comment: How cross browser do you want it? Relating to given answer - `:before` seems [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the left border to a [`:before` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) of the div and remove the divs left border.

**Compatibility:** [All modern browsers and IE8 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

#### Give the `:before`

- `height: 100%` to span the entire height of your div
- `margin-top: -1px` to overlap the top border
- `padding-bottom: 2px` to overlap the bottom border

#### Then use either

`position: absolute` on the `:before` with `position: relative` on the div like this example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
div {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

#### or

`display: inline-block` for the `:before` like this example:

**Note:** You will probably want to use `vertical-align: top / middle / bottom` for the `:before`. This example uses the value `top`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
div {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #939393;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-left: none;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
There is text in this
</div>
```

#### Final result

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Good idea! I don't know why I didn't thought of :before before! 
Applied the second snippet and it worked great

Comment: Oh! If you are using the `display: inline-block` option, you may also want to set `vertical-align` to `top / middle / bottom`. The default value is `baseline` and this can have unintended results. I updated my answer with the vertical align added. If you set `middle` you get bonus vertical alignment included for inline elements :)